# Navigation hover items without moving

Tags: html, css, navigation, hover

I made this navigation:

http://jsfiddle.net/48jd6/

A menu item looks like this:

```
<li><a href="index.html" title="home" class="navTx">home</a></li>
```

When you hover over "home", "about", "works" or "contact", a green border appears. However, while hovering, all the other menu items move because the hovered text becomes bigger.

I can't figure out at all how to stop them from moving. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below code:

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/48jd6/1/)

```
.navTx {
height: 18px;
margin-top: -130px;
display: inline-block;
border:solid 2px transparent;
padding: 12px 20px;
}
```

Comment: That's what I do, the only difference is I usually set the border color to `transparent` so that it'll work on any background.

Comment: the alignment is broken.. :v

Comment: Alignment works again when changing the nav's width. :)

Comment: @john: Yes, You can set the border color to transparent..:)